# Eclipse Workspace resolution - Reference additional artifacts

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, m2eclipse, m2e

We have Maven projects which create an additional jar (which contains only the interfaces) with a different artifactId.

Eclipse Workspace resolution cannot find this jar - I guess because its artifactId is not mentioned in the pom and is not the project name.

I wonder whether I can step in and "tell" m2e that referencing a jar with a certain name means referencing some classes within a given project. Any ideas for that?

Comment: When does Eclipse not find the jar? Is it missing on the classpath and the project won't compile? Or does it just not find the source artifact when opening a class from that additional artifact? How do you publish your artifacts and how do you create your create your Eclipse project file?

Comment: @sebkur Let me try to give some more details and answer your questions along the way: Workspace resolution should magically replace the reference to a jar by the reference to another project in the workspace. This is not about source, but about compiled classes. This automatic replacement does not work if a project produces an additional jar as described above. This additional jar is instead drawn from local or remote repositories (if it exists there). Our Eclipse projects are usual Maven projects.